# PHP: View PDF file inmy site

Tags: php, jquery, pdf, iframe

I need to display a PDF on a website and have it embedded inline.

The following code works if the data attribute is local, but not remote.  I just get a large grey box in place of the PDF.  I'm open to any solution as long as it works in all browsers.  We are using Rails 3 and jQuery.

```
<object data='https://remotesite.com/uploads/pdf/5/mypdf.pdf' type='application/pdf' width='100%' height='100%'>
  <p>
    It appears your Web browser is not configured to display PDF files. 
    No worries, just <a href='https://remotesite.com/uploads/pdf/5/mypdf.pdf'>click here to download the PDF file.</a>
  </p>
</object>
```

And i try this code

```
<iframe src="http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~chong/pubs/oopsla04.pdf" width="100%" height="300">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

But not work with Arabic file like " ملف المتسابقين.pdf" 
Thanks,

Comment: I would suggest trying to change the meta tag for charset encoding to use arabic characters.

Comment: That "Arabic file", is it Arabic because its *name* contains Arabic characters, or because its contents do? It is unclear whether it's the file name is the problem or not.